# Why Python datetime and JS Date does not match?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, pytz, python-dateutil

I have this code, that returns UTC offset from given date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> cet = pytz.timezone("Europe/Moscow")
>>> cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1))
datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSD+4:00:00 DST>)
>>> int(cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1)).utcoffset().seconds/60)
240
```

Ok, do it in JS using this code ( http://jsfiddle.net/nvn1fef0/ )

```
new Date(2000, 5, 1).getTimezoneOffset(); // -180
```

Maybe i doing something wrong? And how i can get `plus-minus` before offset (like in JS result)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my system both Python and Javascript produce the same result (modulo sign):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> import pytz
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Moscow')
>>> dt = tz.localize(datetime(2000, 6, 1), is_dst=None)
>>> print(dt)
2000-06-01 00:00:00+04:00
>>> dt.utcoffset() // timedelta(minutes=1)
240
```

And [`new Date(2000, 6, 1).getTimezoneOffset()`](http://jsfiddle.net/nvn1fef0/1/) returns `-240` (different sign, same value).

Python uses: `local time = utc time + utc offset` definition. While [Javascript uses a different definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset): `utc offset = utc time - local time` i.e., both results are correct and have correct signs for the corresponding definitions.

For a portable Javascript solution, you could use [momentjs library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) that provides access to the same tz database as `pytz` Python module:

```
> var moscow = moment.tz("2000-06-01", "Europe/Moscow");
undefined
> moscow.format()
"2000-06-01T00:00:00+04:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you print the result for the following -

```
print(cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1)).utcoffset())
```

You will notice that it gives a `datetime.timedelta()` object which has both days as well as second.

So for timezones that are `UTC - <something>` , this actually gives days as `-1` and then the remaining in seconds. Example -

```
In [84]: cet = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")

In [87]: cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1)).utcoffset()
Out[87]: datetime.timedelta(-1, 61200)
```

To get the info about the actual offset , you need to use both `days` as well as `seconds` , using a code like (For the above timezone - `America/Los_Angeles`) -

```
In [88]: int((cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1)).utcoffset().days*60*60*24 + cet.localize(datetime.datetime(2000, 6, 1)).utcoffset().seconds)/60)
Out[88]: -420
```

Also, I believe when you are doing - `new Date(2000, 5, 1).getTimezoneOffset();` in javascript, I think it is giving you the timezone offset from UTC for today's date, rather than the date `2000/05/01` (Because for the date  - `2000/05/01` the correct offset is what you are getting from python - `240` ) . You may checkout [`TimezoneJS`](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) for getting the timezone specific as well as date specific offsets, etc.